# Javascript code is running out of memory

Tags: javascript

When I run the below code it crashes browsers or tells me the process is out of memory. I believe I made a mistake. What is the problem with the below code:

```
var primes = new Array();
var nonprimes = new Array();

var factor = function(n){
    for (var i = n; n > 1; i--)
    {
        if (n%i === 0 || n !== i){
            primes.push(i);
        }else{nonprimes.push(i);}
    }
}
factor(2);
console.log(primes);
```

Comment: You have `n > 1`. I think it is supposed to be `i > 1`

Comment: Tip: `new Array()` → `[]`. Also, `n !== i` is going to be `true` for many values of `i`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're decreasing `i` but checking if `n > 1` .

Essentially, you've created an [infinite loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) because you never decrease the value of `n`. The conditions within loops allow execution until they evaluate to `false`. In your example, the condition clause of the for loop will always evaluate to `true` and the loop will continue forever.

Consider:

```
for (var i = n; i > 1; i--){
```

Comment: Just an observation, why do people under the [tag:javascript] tag like making community wiki answers?

Comment: @JesseGood Doing CW on simple questions that have an obvious answer has two benefits. One - it allows a lot of users (who know the answer) to provide fast input, which creates a fast high quality answer to the problem (see how Nile improved my answer). Second - it prevents a lot of immediate "I know it too!" answers from users who want the rep keeping everything clean.

Comment: Thanks for the input (although I should have asked on meta probably).

Answer (score 2):

Your loop will keep running until `n > 1` becomes false, but `n` never changes.