# What does "uncaught exception: out of memory" mean and how do you track the cause?

Tags: javascript, memory, out-of-memory

After extensive googling I got some hits about a PC ram usage, but not about what "out of memory" mean in programming context and how to troubleshoot it. The closest is this:
[Ajax out of memory question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291952/uncaught-exception-out-of-memory-in-ajax-process)

This question does not address the general cause behind "out of memory" and how to diagnose it out of the scope of Ajax (the error also shows "`<unknown>`" in dev tools so its hard to track it).

It may not be that critical to what I am working on, but I am still curious. This can also serve as a good landing page for a common error that has no proper answer thread (yet).

Comment: Most browsers come with tools to diagnose memory issues.

Comment: You understand what the general cause is, right? You just can't find the offending code?

Comment: Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310406/javascript-code-is-running-out-of-memory) for another example

Comment: @bergi it is a problem to find the offending code when it says "unknown". Kind of a novice to memory diagnosis.

Comment: @BarAkiva: I'd go for [binary search debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/843922/1048572) at first - find the minimal code that reproduces the error. Either it's obvious by then where the mistake lies, or you can post that minimal example on SO. If you really want to look at the memory itself, check the "heap profiler" of your devtools.